# laravel 5.3 error : Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Laravel 5.3 
I am trying to get the fields from tables users and mobiles

users table has a primary key id
and my mobiles tables has a field users_id

so I want to get all the numbers of all users_id

```
select u.*,m.mobile,ud.name from users u 
left join userdetails ud on ud.user_id = u.id
left join mobiles m on m.users_id = u.id
where m.mobiletypes_id = 1 and m.deleted_by is null
```

I am trying the above query in eloquent but I am facing an error
undefined property illuminate database eloquent collection

my user model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
         'email', 'password','role_id'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    public function mobile()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\mobile','users_id');
    }

    public function userdetails()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Userdetails');
    }

}
```

my mobile model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class mobile extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'mobiles_id';
    protected $fillable = ['mobile', 'mobiletypes_id', 'users_id', 'created_by', 'updated_by', 'deleted_by', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];




}
```

my controller

public function employeeview(){
   // $user = User::all(); // get all user

```
$userdetails = User::with(['mobile' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('mobiletypes_id', 1);
} ,'userdetails'])->get(); // get all userdetails 

// $mobile = User::with('mobile')->get();

//$userdetails = User::all();
//return $user;
//return view('employeeview',compact('userdetails'));
return view('employeeview')->with('userdetails', $userdetails);
```

}

my view employeeview.blade.php

```
@foreach($userdetails as $u)
                                 <tr>
                                        <td>{{$u->id}} </td>
                                        <td>{{$u->userdetails->name}} </td>
                                        <td>{{$u->email}}</td>
                                        @foreach($u->mobile as $um)
                                        <td>{{$um->mobile}}</td>
                                        @endforeach  
                                    </tr> 

                                 @endforeach
```

Comment: User has many mobiles so `$u->mobile` is not a single mobile but a collection of mobiles

Comment: @apokryfos I have edited some code can you check now

Comment: Are you still getting the same error?

Answer (score 0):

I would first advise to place a dd($userdetails) before the return of the view, in order to check that it is indeed what you're looking for.

If needed, create a variable called

```
$visible = []
```

and place all the visible fields inside it.

Comment: I want all the id from user table , even if there is null in mobile

Comment: try this return:     return view('employeeview', ['userdetails' => $userdetails->toArray()]);

Comment: Error : htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string,